# To create new File extension and launch silverlight App using that

Tags: silverlight-5.0, file-extension

I am creating Silverlight App, at one point I am in need to create new custom File extension , when the user clicks that particulat extension say .xxx , silverlight app should be lauched in browser. This is similar to opening a text document when we click .txt file.

Can any one suggest a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To associate a file to a program, follow the following steps.

1. In Windows 7 Open the Control Panel (Small Icon View) and click on the **Default Programs**.
2. Click on the **Associate a file type or protocol with a program** link.
3. Under the left **Name** column, select a file **extension type** or **protocol** that you want to change what program will open it by default, then click on the **Change Program** button.
4. A dialog box opens with name "**Opens With**". Choose the default program in the list or search and select any other program.

So associate a silverlight file, **Xbap** file extension is used, which is already associated with Windows Presentation Foundation Host. You can associate xbap files with Internet Explorer.

**OR**

If you created your own custom extension file, you can associate this file in the same way as mentioned above, to Internet Explorer or to Windows Presentation Foundation Host.

Comment: Silverlight uses .XAP, not .XBAP